# pkeys are immutable on OpenSSL 3.0\e[0m (OpenSSL::PKey::PKeyError)

Tags: openssl, fastlane

Does anyone know how I can use the existing private key and public key to encrypt the message? The keys are immutable now.

```
Fastfile:821:in `private_key=': \e[31m[!] pkeys are immutable on OpenSSL 3.0\e[0m (OpenSSL::PKey::PKeyError)
```

Environment:

```
ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [arm64-darwin21]
openssl (3.1.0, default: 2.2.0)
fastlane | 2.212.2 | ✅ Up-To-Date
```

Sample Code:

```
def get_force_update_message
    message = "message"
    private_key = "sample_private_key"
    public_key = "sample_public_key"

    # encrypt
    group = OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Group.new('secp256k1')
    key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(group)
    key.private_key = OpenSSL::BN.new(private_key, 16)

    signature = key.dsa_sign_asn1(message)
    signature_base64 = Base64.encode64(signature).gsub("\n", "")

    # verify
    public_key_bn = OpenSSL::BN.new(public_key, 16)
    key.public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Point.new(group, public_key_bn)
    key.dsa_verify_asn1(message, signature)

    return "#{message}&#{signature_base64}"
  end
```

Error:

```
[17:13:51]: Error in your Fastfile at line 821
[17:13:51]:     819:        group = OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Group.new('secp256k1')
[17:13:51]:     820:        key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(group)
[17:13:51]:  => 821:        key.private_key = OpenSSL::BN.new(private_key, 16)
[17:13:51]:     822:    
[17:13:51]:     823:        signature = key.dsa_sign_asn1(message)
[17:13:51]: pkeys are immutable on OpenSSL 3.0

+------+----------------------+-------------+
|             fastlane summary              |
+------+----------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action               | Time (in s) |
+------+----------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform     | 0           |
| 2    | xcodes               | 0           |
| 3    | ensure_env_vars      | 0           |
| 4    | set_info_plist_value | 0           |
| 5    | ensure_env_vars      | 0           |
+------+----------------------+-------------+

[17:13:51]: fastlane finished with errors

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...

Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/new
Run `fastlane env` to append the fastlane environment to your issue
Fastfile:821:in `private_key=': \e[31m[!] pkeys are immutable on OpenSSL 3.0\e[0m (OpenSSL::PKey::PKeyError)
    from Fastfile:821:in `get_force_update_message'
    from Fastfile:252:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:47:in `cruise_lane'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:187:in `call'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:157:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/runner.rb:444:in `run_active_command'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:124:in `run!'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/delegates.rb:18:in `run!'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:354:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:43:in `start'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:123:in `take_off'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/bin/fastlane:25:in `load'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/bin/fastlane:25:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you solve this, Yk Poh?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. In my case, this error was triggered in two instances: when calling `generate_key` and when attempting to set the `private_key` value.

To generate the private key, instead of calling e.g. `key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new('prime256v1')` and then calling `key.generate_key`, simply call `key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.generate('prime256v1')` (i.e. replace the `new` with `generate`).

In my case I was setting the `private_key` to `nil`, because it was meant to be a public key. Turns out that when generating a key, it contains both private and public keys now in OpenSSL 3, so my code was simplified like this:

[image]

I hope this helps. It took me awhile to figure these things out. Luckily in my case it was just a rspec that was failing, so it was a bit easier to solve IMO.

This is the documentation that helped me: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey/EC.html

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation from this post worked for me: https://github.com/ruby/openssl/issues/498#issuecomment-1065574184

If you already have a generated OpenSSL::PKey::EC key, you can do:

```
asn1 = OpenSSL::ASN1::Sequence([
    OpenSSL::ASN1::Sequence([
        OpenSSL::ASN1::ObjectId("id-ecPublicKey"),
        OpenSSL::ASN1::ObjectId(curve_used_for_initial_ec_key)
    ]),
    OpenSSL::ASN1::BitString(initial_ec_key.public_key.to_octet_string(:uncompressed))
])

ec_key_with_desired_public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(asn1.to_der)
```